# Setting different compiler levels for different source folders in eclipse in same project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a project that is build using ant and now i am trying to convert into one that is build in eclipse.

The ant files describes different compiler versions for different course folders i.e few are compiled using jdk 5, few using 6 and still few using 4.

How can we configure the project in eclipse to use different compiler levels in eclipse for different folders in same project.

I noticed that they had this bug lined up in eclipse and they said to release it on 3.5 and i am using 4.3. So it think the feature should be there.

Comment: You can likely use 'ant builders' to just have eclipse call your ant scripts to build the code.

Comment: The project can be build using ANT but i need eclipse to refactor the project and if not configured properly in eclipse the build automatic feature would not be able to help me in finding the compilation issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such feature does not exist. You will need to create multiple Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you think twice before making a change in that direction.
ANT might not be the best build tool, but switching to Eclipse is way worse as you tight yourself not only to an IDE, but also to a specific configuration of both your instance and your project, making it less portable and more fragile than before.

I would rather suggest that you split your project into different modules/projects and use maven (integration with Maven and Eclipse is ok for simple builds) to organize both you CLI and Eclipse build procedures.

Comment: I need to refactor the Project to use different libraries so I want to to use Eclipse for building the project. Is there a way in eclipse to describe different compiler levels for different source folders.